# How are Wikipedia subcategories meant, semantically?

Tags: wikipedia

Let's have a look at the category

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:British_politicians

Theresa May is not in it. So let's see:

- Theresa May is in [Category:20th-century_British_women_politicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:20th-century_British_women_politicians)
- which is in [Category:20th-century_British_politicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:20th-century_British_politicians)
- which is in [Category:British_politicians_by_century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:British_politicians_by_century)
- which indeed is in [Category:British_politicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:British_politicians).

So those categories seem to be inclusive: the items of a subcategory are thought to be in the parent category as well.

However, then we have the following problem:

- The [2019_Conservative_Party_leadership_election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Conservative_Party_leadership_election) is in the category [Category:2019_Conservative_Party_(UK)_leadership_election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:2019_Conservative_Party_(UK)_leadership_election)
- which is in [Category:Theresa_May](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Theresa_May)
- which also is in [Category:20th-century_British_women_politicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:20th-century_British_women_politicians)

Uh, so this means that the **2019 Conservative Party leadership election** is a British politician too?

So there seem to be two kinds of "subcategory relations":

- this category is a subcategory, all its items belong to the parent category (Theresa May --> British politician)
- this category is just related to that parent category (2019 election --> Theresa May)

Is that just messy, or am I missing something to distinguish between the two types?

Comment: I don't believe you are missing anything, it is messy like that. The categories are not a proper ontology.

Comment: This is due to the fact that categories are annotated in article pages. I don't think that adding a category to a category page results in the super-category being added in all the sub-category pages. There are bots that do services of this kind on Wikipedia, but I'd love to see a systemic and up-to-date review of what bots are actually running.

Comment: @mapto Can you please elaborate on "I don't think that adding a category to a category page results in the super-category being added in all the sub-category pages." ? Not sure I understand. Is that explained in detail somewhere?

Comment: You can edit WIkipedia and change it, or propose that change. You can also change items in Wikidata. WIkidata is used in creating the infoboxes on Wikipedia pages.

Comment: @knb: I see. Does that explain mapto's comment?